# Erro ao alterar um conteúdo gerado dentro de uma tag <span>, gerado automaticamente no Woocommerce

Tags: php, html, jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

Tentando alterar a palavra "New!" gerada automaticamente no woocommerce conforme abaixo:

```html
<span class="label-new">New!</span>
```

E usando o trecho do jQuery abaixo

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".label-new").html("Novo!");

});
</script>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Aparece a mensagem no console assim:

> Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function
>       at (index):864

Que é o local da linha do código

> $(document).ready(function(){

Gostaria de ter o seguinte resultado:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

   $(".label-new").html("Novo!");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="label-new">New!</span>
```

E no caso não estou obtendo.

Como resolver esse problema?

Comment: Tente assim: `window.onload = function(){
   $(".label-new").html("Novo!");
}
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Isso acontece pois seu tema carregou a biblioteca jquery depois de executar seu código: Para adicionar um script no wordpress você precisa usar a função `add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'function_name')`.

O exemplo abaixo mostra como fazer isso utilizando apenas vanilla.js(javascript). Se caso você precisa utilizar jquery terás que registrar a biblioteca com a função `wp_enqueue_script()`.

Observe que estou executando o script apenas nas páginas e posts:
 `is_single() && is_page()`.

Você pode tirar esse trecho porém seu script ira executar em todas as rotas do site.

Adicione isso ao `functions.php` do tema:

**Apenas com vanila.js:**

```
if (! function_exists('mudar_span')){
    /**
     * Muda o conteúdo da tag span com a classe .label-new
     */
    function mudar_span(){
        if (is_single() && is_page()) {
            ?>                
            <script>
                function ready (fn) {
                    if (document.attachEvent ? document.readyState === "complete" : document.readyState !== "loading")
                    {
                        return fn();
                    }
                    else{
                        return document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', fn);
                    }
                }
                ready(function () {
                    el = document.querySelectorAll('.label-new span');                   
                    for (let n = 0; n < el.length; n++) {
                         el[n].innerHTML = 'Novo !';  
                    }

                })
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'mudar_span' );
```

Para poder usar o jquery precisas certificar que ele está sendo incluído no cabeçalho:

**Usando o jquery:**

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js', array('jquery'), '', false);
```

O ultimo atributo `false` determina o carregamento do `script` no `head` do site. Caso for `true` o `script` é carregado no `footer`.
Agora você pode registrar o script:

```
if (! function_exists('mudar_span_jquery')){
    /**
     * Muda o conteúdo da tag span com a classe .label-new
     */
    function mudar_span_jquery(){
        if (is_single() && is_page()) {
            ?>                
            <script>
              $(document).ready(function(){

                   $(".label-new").html("Novo!");

              });
            </script>
            <?php
        }
    }

}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts' , 'mudar_span_jquery' );
```

Comment: Tentei executar ambos os códigos, porém nenhum rodou, não estão inserindo nos código fonte das páginas, o `wp_enqueue_script()` coloco dentro do `functions.php` do tema né?

Comment: Sim. dentro do arquivo functions.php do tema. Onde está sendo exibido essa span ? numa página, em uma postagem ? na administração ?